# Failure to run application on the device IOS with Tibar module

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, barcode-scanner

I have a problem with the tibar (barcode scanner http://code.google.com/p/tibar/), when run on my iphone, xcode returns an error exit 65, I've outlined below:

```
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
Ld build/Scannn.build/Debug-iphoneos/Scannn.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Scannn normal armv6
(1 failure)
EXIT CODE WAS: 65

Exception detected in script:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.0.1.GA2/iphone/builder.py", line 1465, in main
execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.0.1.GA2/iphone/builder.py", line 1224, in execute_xcode
output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.0.1.GA2/iphone/run.py", line 41, in run
sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

if I run the application directly in xcode, it works correctly.

My configuration:

- Titanium SDK: 2.0.1.GA2
- XCode: 4.3.2
- iOS: 5.1.1 (iphone 4s)
- Tibar: 0.4.2

Thanks!!!

Comment: I found the solution, you must specify the module tibar frameworks to use. I edited the line in the file **/Users/name/Library/Application/Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/tibar/0.4.2/module.xcconfig** and added the following:
`OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework QuartzCore /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib`

Comment: I just got this working on a new project with the edit above. Thanks @Gonzalo!